# What is the need to return a function object while creating a data set using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to Machine Learning and I am trying to create a Machine Learning Model using the Tensorflow API from the tutorial in the Tensorflow documentation [from here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/linear)
But I am having trouble understanding this part of the code

```
 def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  def input_function():          # inner function, this will be returned
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))     # create tf.data.Dataset object with data and its label
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000)   # randomize order of data
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)      # split dataset into batches of 32 and repeat process for number of epochs
    return ds  # return a batch of the dataset
  return input_function  # return a function object for use
```

Then storing the output of the function in a variable

```
train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)
```

And at last training the model with the data set

```
linear_est.train(train_input_fn)
```

I failed to realize what we are trying to do when by just returning the function name of the inner-function in make_input_function instead of just returning our data set and passing it to train the model.

I am a beginner in Python and just started to learn Machine Learning and I am unable to find a proper answer to my question so if anyone can kindly explain it in a beginner friendly way I would be very much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I failed to realize what we are trying to do when by just returning the function name of the inner-function in make_input_function instead of just returning our data set and passing it to train the model.

In python programming, this is called **Currying**, It is used to transform multiple-argument function into single argument function by evaluating incremental nesting of function arguments. Currying also mends one argument to another forms a relative pattern while execution.

In tensorflow, based on the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier#train).

```
train(
    input_fn, hooks=None, steps=None, max_steps=None, saving_listeners=None
)
```

The method train of the estimator is expecting a parameter `input_fn`. The reason is that everytime you call the `Estimator.train()` it will create a new graph by invoking either `input_fn` and `model_fn` and connecting them together. If you supply either a tensor or a dataset it will lead to different errors.